# How to pass/generate table with parameters from one page to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i having a scenario where i am generating a dynamic table along with the dynamic button  and when ever user clicks that button it has to get that row value and it has generate another dynamic table by taking this value as parameter .Till now i tried generating a dynamic table and with button and passed a parameter to that function here i stuck how to pass /accept a parameter to that function so that by using ajax call it can generate another dynamic table.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx,
        data: "Id=" + clO + Name_=" + cl+ "",

        success: function (resp) {

            var Location = resp;
            var tr;
            for (var i = 0; i < Location.length; i++) {

                tr = tr + "<tr>

                tr = tr + "<td style='height:20px' align='right'>" + Location[i].Amount + "</td>";

                tr = tr + "<td style='height:20px' align='right'>" + Location[i].Name + "</td>";

                tr = tr + '<td><input type="button" class="nav_button" onclick="test(\'' + Location[i].Amount + '\',\'' + Location[i].Name + '\')"></td>';

                tr = tr + "</tr>";

            };

            document.getElementById('d').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('Wise').innerHTML = "<table id='rt'>" + "<thead ><tr><th style='height:20px'>Amount</th>" + "<th style='height:20px'>Name</th>""</tr></thead>"
                + tr + "<tr><td align='left' style='height:20px'><b>Total:"+ TotBills +"</b></td><td style='height:20px' align='right'><b></b></td></tr>" +

                "</table>";
            document.getElementById('Wise').childNodes[0].nodeValue = null;

        },
        error: function (e) {

            window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom("error");


        }



function test(value,val1,val2) {

    navigator.notification.alert(value + ";" + val1 + ";" + val2);
    // here i have to pass the another ajax by basing on the the onclick
}
```

so here in the function i have to pass the parameters and have to display in the new page and how is it possible ?

Comment: unless you have a single page app, your best bet is leveraging local storage or binding to the window.

Comment: @im_benton Then the best thing is to replace the table in the same div then ?

Comment: @Taplar i have a page named 1.html in which by using aajax im displaying dynamic data in the form of table at the end of the each row there will be a button and after clicking on that it has to open a  2.html page display another table in it

Comment: @Taplar i ma actually not directly passing values to it . after onclick the function accepts the arguments and then it will display in the new page

Comment: @Taplar in a div

Comment: Where are you getting the markup for that div from?

Comment: @Taplar in the function it self document.getElementById('Wise').innerHTML = "<table id='rt'>"

Comment: No dude.  You're question talks about passing a parameter to a 'new page', but what you are saying now is there is no new page.  You are adding new markup on the same page.  I'm asking how the new markup that is put in that div is being created.  Is it that ajax call you have up above?  If so we need more context into the function that that ajax is inside and the logic that calls that function.

Answer (score 1):

To pass data from a page to another your best bet is localStorage and SessionStorage;

`SessionStorage` - Similar to a cookie that expires when you close the browser. It has the same structure as the localStorage, but there is no way to change its permanence time, whenever closing will be deleted.

`LocalStorage` - This is similar to a cookie, but it never expires, so while there were records in the AppCache for that domain, the variable will exist (unless the user creates a routine to remove it).

Both attributes were added by HTML5. The above items called web storage. But there are other forms of local storage through HTML5, such as WebSQL database, Indexed Database (IndexDB), as well as conventional files (File Access).

Ex:

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");

// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Is it what you meant ?

Comment: with out using local or session it is not possible ?

Comment: I would to understand better your necessity.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're after, but I think I see where you're headed.  From the code you included, it seems like you want something like this instead:

```
// This will take the user to a separate page, passing your parameters
function test(val1,val2) {
    window.location.href("/UrlGoesHere?Amount=" + val1 + "&Name=" + val2);
}
```

Another option, based on what you've said, is to redraw the table.  You could do that with something like this:

```
function test(val1,val2) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/UrlGoesHere",
        data: "Amount=" + val1 + "&Name=" + val2,

        success: function (resp) {
           // redraw table here
        }
     });
}
```